# PrimeFaces: How to increase the rendered size of a MindmapNode

Tags: primefaces

I am following the PrimeFaces MindMap example from:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/mindmap.jsf

My question is: How do I increase the size of the "bubble" (MindmapNode) so that I can display more text within it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at generated source and found that size is controlled by rx and ry in eclipse element. Just put your numbers there. [Here is some source](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/mindmap/mindmap.js?r=7587) of mindMap maybe will be useful.

Comment: Even though you've posted the link to the code, your answer doesn't remotely tie up to the question at hand. A more descriptive answer (supported by an example) is what the OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

I spent forever trying to find out how to do this, so for anyone else who struggles, heres how to do it.

Open your primefaces jar file in a ZIP program such as WinZip.
Navigate to META-INF -> resources -> primefaces -> mindmap and open the mindmap.js file.
When I open it up even in an editor such as Notepad++ it is displayed entirely on one line. Therefore the easiest approach is just to search the file for this line:

```
raphael.ellipse
```

Within the brackets after that line are 4 values. The last 2 are the ones you are looking for. The first of the two is width and the last is height.

All you need to do then is to save the mindmap.js file, go back to WinZip and update the files in the jar, go to your project in Eclipse (or your chosen IDE), refresh the project and restart the server.

And your done.

I hope this helps somebody